# Property access is not allowed yet in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have one simple function for delete account from my database. I have written it like below

```
public function removeAccount($email) {
    $response = array('code' => 0, 'error' => false);
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows) {
        $user   =  $result->fetch_assoc();
        $id = $user['id'];
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM number_list WHERE user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM number_status WHERE user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO old_user(email,serial,premium) SELECT email, device_id, membership FROM user WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
            $response["code"] = 1;
        }
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Its giving me warning in below line

```
if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
```

I have searched way for solve it but does not getting idea whats wrong and what can fix it. Please check and let me know if someone can have idea about it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think you can use `$stmt->affected_rows` after a `$stmt->close()` call. You should record the value of `affected_rows` before you call `close()`.

Comment: @Nick You are right. Thanks a lot. It have solved my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->affected_rows > 0) { $response["code"] = 1; }
$stmt->close();
```

In this case, we checked to see if any rows got updated. For reference, here's the usage for `mysqli::$affected_rows` return values.

**-1** - query returned an error; redundant if there is already error handling for `execute()`

**0** - no records updated on `UPDATE`, no rows matched the `WHERE` clause or no query has been executed

**Greater than 0** - returns number of rows affected; comparable to `mysqli_result::$num_rows` for `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get the number of affected rows from a closed statement.
Instead of

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
    $response["code"] = 1;
}
```

Use

```
$stmt->execute();
$num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
$stmt->close();
if ($num_affected_rows) {
    $response["code"] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this error, but the one I had today was one I have not found documented anywhere.

I had two (2) copies of same virtual machine running and they were both competing in some way that I do not understand well enough to explain, but going into VirtualBox and shutting one of them off solved the problem.

I know this an obscure scenario, but if anyone else runs across the same I hope my answer stops them from wasting time on it like I did.